# Do PHP Core & Default preinstalled libraries use shell_exec anywhere?

Tags: php

I am planning to disable 'shell_exec' on 'php.ini' but, I am wondering if PHP Core & preinstalled libraries use it anywhere.
If they do, will disabling 'shell_exec' cause any conflict to running services?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't used internally. Disabling that will be safe, unless your own code (or framework) makes use of it.